# How to open Mac image formats on Windows

Tags: windows, mac, images

I have some images from a Mac and I want view them under Windows but they don't show automatically. Is there any software that can open them under Windows?

I'm talking about pictures and not CD/DVD images.

Comment: What format are the images in? There shouldn't be any compatibility issues.

Comment: that's what I thought but some images don't open under windows! some *.tif can be opened and the others I get wrong format

Comment: There are no Mac specific image formats these days. We need to know the format of the images you are trying to open to be able to help you.

Comment: You only told us what format DOES work, not what format the images that do not work are in.

Answer (score 6):

For some silly reason that I have yet to discover, sometimes when you have a picture (graphic) on OSX, it will maintain it's mime type, but it won't have an extension.

OSX will know what to do with it, but Windows won't - since the file has no extension.

Make sure the file has an extension. Make sure the file doesn't have 'Hide Extension' turned on, and ensure you see .tiff at the end of the file.

Comment: that's it, most of them has no extension or are .-tif

Answer (score 1):

Any of the software listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/6925/best-image-viewers-for-windows) should work fine. Images are universal.

Answer (score 1):

[TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Flexible_options) is a strange beast. It's not actually an image format; it's a container into which files go. A TIFF can contain several files -- perhaps a high-resolution JPEG, a low-resolution thumbnail, and a text file that documents them.

That said, there has been some quasi-standardization over time. Most image apps agree on a relatively small number of image formats that can go into a TIFF. But there are still some problems. In particular, there are "Mac TIFF" and "Windows TIFF" files whose contents are sometimes not entirely compatible due to big-endian, little-endian issues.

I haven't run into this problem recently, however, but it was huge about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I use [IrfanView](http://irfanview-portable.10001downloads.com/) (portable) to view my images. I switched from the default windows viewer (photo gallery) as it didn't show my animated gifs in motion and wrote changes to images without clear confirmation. From what I've seen it's the default image viewer on most folks' windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

All modern image formats are the same no matter what platform you use to create them. Maybe the files are corrupt, or the editor your using doesn't support the file format. (I know a lot of programs don't do .tif)